# Intranet zone settings apply to Edge and Chrome, but not to Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, group-policy, internet-security

We have GPO settings active that place a certain website https://www.example.com into the trustworthy *intranet* zone. The setting (User Settings -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> Security Page -> Site to Zone Assignment List) still has good old IE in its name, but apparently should apply generally. At least this used to work across all browsers in the past.

Accordingly, files that are downloaded from https://www.example.com are considered "harmless" (as in: right click-properties does *not* show a "This file came from another computer and might be blocked ..." warning, or in case of e.g. Word documents: a yellow warning bar is *not* shown when opening the file).

At least, this works as desired in Edge and Chrome. I also verified that it is not the case that Edge and Chrome never block files from the "wild"; e.g., sample documents from https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-doc-download/ are correctly marked as "dangerous". This shows that the setting is indeed used to distinguish "good" from "evil" downloads, as desired.

However, it seems that the setting does *not* apply to Firefox. That is, downloading the very same file from https://www.example.com using Firefox produces a file that is considered "dangerous". I am very sure that this is a fairly recent problem and used to work as desired for Firefox as well until a few weeks ago.
Unfortunately, I cannot pin down the moment of failure with enough certainty do decide whether the change happened in connection with (a) a Firefox version upgrade, (b) some Windows update, (c) changes to company GPO, or (d) perhaps anything else.

**Q:** How can I ensure that the desired zone settings also apply to Firefox downloads? That is, files from the configured site shall be considered harmless while general downloads from the wild are still considered dangerous by the operating system? Is there perhaps a FF-specific setting with the same semantics?